# Es6 arrow function 'this' in an object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, arrow-functions

I have the following code where I am looping over an object and displaying its property values or calling the value if its a function.

```
 let person = {
  fname: "Joseph",
  lname: "Michuki",
  age: 22,
  profession: "developer",
  address: "10105550-81 Othaya",
  fullname: () => this.fname + " " + this.lname
};

for(i in person){
    if(typeof person[i] === 'function'){
        console.log(person[i]()); // this logs undefined since the value of this defaults to window which has no fname or lname variables
        console.log(person.i); //this results in a type error since i is a string and not a function
        console.log(person[i].call(person)); //this logs undefined undefined since the 'this' passed is ignored
    }else {
        console.log(person[i]);
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I refer to the 'fullname' function of the person object inside the loop so that it logs the correct value?
Thank you.

Comment: `person[i]();` is correct. The problem is how you define `username`, not how you call it. Use `function` function syntax or method syntax, not arrow function syntax. Arrow functions inherit `this` from where they're defined, not how they're called like other functions.

Comment: Hello, here is my solution, I think you should return a value in your lamba function (fullname) and call it using person[i].fullname() => which concat fname + lname instead of this.fname and this.lname ;)

    fullname: function () {
       return fname + ' ' + lname;
    }
    // to set a value => person[i].fullname = fname + ' ' + lname;